# Pandas dataframe transformation: adding columns from dictionary k-v pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transform a DataFrame looking like this:

```
         dictionary
0  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
1  {'c': 4, 'b': 3}
```

from

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame()
df['dictionary'] = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'b': 3,'c':4}]
```

onto a DataFrame looking like this:

```
         dictionary    a  b    c
0  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}  1.0  2  NaN
1  {'c': 4, 'b': 3}  NaN  3  4.0
```

where (of course) the order of the columns does not matter.

How can I do this without explicitly looping through the dictionaries or the rows ?

Answer (score 4):

A vectorized approach by converting the given series to it's `list` representation and then performing concatenation column-wise:

```
pd.concat([df['dictionary'], pd.DataFrame(df['dictionary'].values.tolist())], axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a pd.Series transformation and concat the two:

```
pd.concat([df, df['dictionary'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
Out: 
         dictionary    a    b    c
0  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  {'b': 3, 'c': 4}  NaN  3.0  4.0
```

Or you could use `join`

```
In [4]: df.join(df.dictionary.apply(pd.Series))
Out[4]:
           dictionary    a    b    c
0  {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  {u'c': 4, u'b': 3}  NaN  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: Neat, `df.join(df.dictionary.apply(pd.Series))` would work too.

Comment: @JohnGalt Thank you. That looks much cleaner.

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks! Looks like your solution is the cleanest, would you make it an answer?

Comment: I think, the base for the solution came from ayhan's idea. Happy to add it to his answer.

Comment: @JohnGalt I actually didn't add it thinking you might want to add another answer. Feel free to edit this answer or add another one.